# Invoke action on SQL Server 2000 Table Change

Tags: sql-server

There any way to let an application know if there is any specific change on a database table (like an insert, update...) without checking the database in a specific interval? The database server is a SQL Server 2000 Enterprise Version

Something like triggers but on the application level.

Thanks,
rAyt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do it using [SQLDependency classes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178604.aspx), I would think. Though they are normally used for caching, you could probably do other stuff. Have a read of [Using SqlDependency for data change events](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/chatter.aspx) .

Comment: Thanks, just added the info that it is a SQL Server 2000 ;)

Comment: Well, you can still use Cache Dependcy even with SQL Server 2000 (though it's not as good, granted!) See http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mosessaur/sqlcachedependency01292006135138PM/sqlcachedependency.aspx?ArticleID=3caa7d32-dce0-44dc-8769-77f8448e76bc

Answer (score 1):

Step 1 would be to upgrade to a database server that's not about ten years old.
Step 2 would be to use the DDL Triggers technology of SQL Server 2008 to solve the problem.

Comment: unfortunately I cannot force my company to buy licenses for new SQL Servers.

Comment: No doubt. Just make your superiors aware you're left to solve a problem already solved in the later release.